# How to display the error message in ValidationSummary and just * at the property level

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here's the property

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Device Name is required")]
public string DeviceName { get; set; }
```

I'd like to have the same effect like in WebForm, i.e. you can decide to display the error message in the ValidationSummary while just display an `*` at the property level.

I've tried to play with this with **true** and **false**, but the error is still being displayed at the property level:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Also, tried to put a `*` in between quote, but it didn't work.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeviceName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: are you trying to show all validation errors in summary instead of underneath of input

Comment: Yes. Like in Webforms. The reason is that there are so many fields to display. That's why, if something goes wrong, the easier can read the message error and instantly know where to go. Otherwise, displaying message next to each field will impact the layout and also force the user to look for the location of the error.

Comment: Did you try to use custom html method?

Answer (score 0):

can you try to create your custom `ValidationMessageFor` method. You should be sure that you declare your static helper class in the System.Web.Mvc.Html namespace.

```
public static class Validator
{
    public static MvcHtmlString YourValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
        span.InnerHtml = "*"
        span.AddCssClass("error-box");

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(span.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
}

// html
// displays all validation errors as a summary
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })  

// displays "*" for all field validations underneath input
@Html.YourValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeviceName)
```

Comment: What this helper does is to display an `asterisk` on the page even when the page is not being submitted.

Comment: @Richard77 did you try ? It should display error messages after form submitted

Comment: When the place loads, it displays an `asterisk`. I doesn't wait for the page to post-back. I've put a breakpoints inside the method. Doesn't this `helper method` supped to check first whether the property is part of the dictionary that flag all the properties (or something similar)?

Comment: I think if there is a way to access the `ModelState` dictionary and verify whether the the property is part the dictionary, it'll be easier to decide whether to display the asterisk.

Comment: @Richard77 you can check your modelstate in view with if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField("FIELD_NAME")) then parse asteriks according to this control

Comment: I think that the right way to go. However, given the definition of the `YourValidationMessageFor`, I don't see to access it from the view. Should I modify my model to pass an extra field that tell whether this field failed the validation?